# Using CoreData, am I able to store UITextView text and retrieve this from a UITableView row?

Tags: swift

In Swift, I have created **two** separate VC's, one is a `UITextView` and the other is a `UITableView`. The `UITableView` is like a list of projects, which **individually** can be swiped to *Edit/Delete*. If chosen **Edit**, it segues to the `UITextView`. By using **CoreData**, which I happen to be new to, I want to make this text/data inside the `UITextView` able to be retrieved again by swiping Edit on the `UITableView` row. So basically, if a UITableViewRow has been already created and text has been added in its `UITextView`, how is it possible for the TableRow(project) to be directed specifically to the saved `UITextView`? I'm just wanting to know, is this possible? This is what I plan to do in the future:

**Make it so:**

- When a User creates a new project (in `UITableView` (as a row)) this creates a completely new UITextView that can be edited, saved and deleted.
- When a User chooses to Edit an existent `UITableViewRow` (project) it will segue to the UITextView with the data it had when created.

Is there anything StackOverflow users can tell me to guide me? Maybe what I will use for specifics etc.

Thanks heaps! Appreciated

UPDATE, CODE:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var projects: [String] = []
    var deleted: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "FourthViewController" {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as FourthViewController
            destination.deletedItems = deleted
        } else {
            fatalError("unhandled segue \"\(segue.identifier)\"")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Use this for swipe table view cell

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            self.deleted.append(self.projects[indexPath.row])
            projects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) } }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return projects.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        // Set the label text as the project name
        cell.textLabel!.text = projects[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        if buttonIndex == 1 {
            if let name = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text {
                projects.append(name)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // Add button

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Enter the title", message: "This will be the name of your project", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")

        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Continue")
        alert.show()
    }

    // Swipe

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {

        // Delete

        var deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(self.tableView, commitEditingStyle: .Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            println(self.projects)
            println(self.deleted)
            return

        })

        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    // Edit


        var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


            let editMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Edit this project", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

            let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
                var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as ThirdViewController
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

            editMenu.addAction(editAction)
            editMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


            self.presentViewController(editMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()


        return [deleteButton, editAction]






    }
}
```

Code for TextView:

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTextView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        // Combine the new text with the old
        let combinedText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

        // Create attributed version of the text
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: combinedText)
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: textView.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

        // Get the padding of the text container
        let padding = textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding

        // Create a bounding rect size by subtracting the padding
        // from both sides and allowing for unlimited length
        let boundingSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width - padding * 2, CGFloat.max)

        // Get the bounding rect of the attributed text in the
        // given frame
        let boundingRect = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(boundingSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

        // Compare the boundingRect plus the top and bottom padding
        // to the text view height; if the new bounding height would be
        // less than or equal to the text view height, append the text
        if (boundingRect.size.height + padding * 2 <= textView.frame.size.height){
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Edit(sender: AnyObject) {
        editButton.title = "Save"
    }




}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO, but this GitHub repo seems to do most of what you mentioned https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely do able. I am sure there are multiple ways to accomplish this, however, I would suggest passing this data through the prepareForSegue.

The first thing you will want to do is create a var on the textViewController to store the passing data object (this will need to be a var of the type of object being sent). Once you have created this var you can fetch the data in your prepareForSegue call and then pass it to the textViewControllers var.

Example of this might look like:

---

### NSManagedObjects

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    @objc(Project)
    class Project: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var text: String
        @NSManaged var person: Person

    }


import Foundation
import CoreData

    @objc(Person)
    class Person: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var name: String
        @NSManaged var tasks: NSSet

    }
```

---

### TableViewController

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
   // First get the cell that was selected
   let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
   // Next setup your destination view controller
   let textViewVC = segue.destinationViewController as ProjectTextViewVC
   // Now fetch the individual object for the select cell
   let project = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Project // Replace 'Project' with the name of your NSManagedObject
   // Last thing is to pass over the object to the destination view controller. 
   textViewVC.project = project 
}
```

---

### TextViewController

```
class ProjectTextViewController: UITextViewController {

    var project: Project? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       textArea.text = project.text
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added the code for Both VC's in the update, can you please help me solve this ?

Comment: I am confused what my Name of the NSManagedObject would be??

Comment: Have you created NSManagedObjects for each entity in core data? This can be easily done by highlighting all entities and selecting the 'Editor' menu option followed by 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass...'. These will be needed for communicating with specific objects in core data.

Comment: I have not yet created any entities in CoreData. What entities would I have to create? Would i only create an entity named "text" of type "string"?

Comment: So, if you have not yet created any entities what are you retrieving data from? Based off your question is sounds like you have core data setup and are ready to fetch data. Is this not the case?

Comment: Perhaps check out this [core data example](https://github.com/TreverP/NSPredicateExample) on github. It is not specifically using a textViewController, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: I only just recently implemented coredata, i have not setup entities yet.

Comment: I would suggest getting core data setup first. You are going to need some type of data store to fetch data from. I guess I am not sure what type of answer you are looking for. It seems as though your question is related to something that is further down the road than where you are in development.

Comment: Yes, i thought that this process would not take very long, i am 15 and still learning programming haha. I have downloaded your github repo, should I just study this and try and copy it and implement it although using a uitextview for mine? I've tried to solve this for a few months now and this is the closest i have ever gotten to a good answer haha. I really don't think I will be able to do this, although I have 2 weeks of holidays and really want to finish my app.

Comment: Kudos for making attempts and getting into programming! May I suggest something... I would start from from scratch with the intent of accomplishing one thing, say setting up a core data stack. For learning I wouldn't suggest copying someone's code for use until you are to the point you can look at code and understand the basics of what it is doing. Instead of copying code I would suggest using others' code as guidelines and examples. It seems as though you are trying to tackle the whole pie. Take small slices. This will benefit you in the end. Best of luck